# "Null Pointer Exception" Animating sprite in cocos2d android

Tags: android, cocos2d

I am converting [this monkey jump game tutorial in android](http://www.raywenderlich.com/7884/how-to-build-a-monkey-jump-game-using-cocos2d-physicseditor-texturepacker-part-2). I have done til monkey sliding right to left and left to right but I am stuck in the part of monkey walking animation. I have tried but getting the "Null Pointer Exception"

This is my code

```
CCSpriteFrame frame = CCSpriteFrameCache.spriteFrameByName("left_1.png");
walkAnimation.addFrame(frame);
CCSpriteFrame frame2 = CCSpriteFrameCache.spriteFrameByName("left_2.png");
walkAnimation.addFrame(frame2);
monkey.addAnimation(walkAnimation);
CCAnimate  wAction = CCAnimate.action(walkAnimation,true);
monkey.runAction(wAction);
```

Comment: Where  are you getting the Null exception? probably you didn't start `walkAnimation`, check your code.

Comment: i have start the walkAnimation is the object of CCAnimation.

Comment: This is pretty basic debugging. Without a line number or more context we are just guessing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn how to read the stack trace. I suggest you read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html).

Comment: This is a comment. While useful, it's not an answer to the question.